# Change XML path string to UPPERCASE in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I want to change ://データベース/PO/Tbl_PO_H/DATA  to UPPERCASE by using this:

```
 @xml.nodes(upper('//データベース/PO/Tbl_PO_H/DATA'))AS TEMPTABLE(TBL_PO_H)
```

but it return an error:

```
Argument 1 of the XML data type method "nodes" should be a string literal.
```

Comment: Wrap the argument as a string as the error message tells you.

Comment: Then use a string literal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use T-SQL's abilities or call `XQuery` to help you:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = N'<root><test>//データベース/PO/Tbl_PO_H/DATA</test></root>';
SELECT UPPER(@xml.value(N'(/root/test/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')) AS Use_a_TSQL_method
      ,@xml.value(N'upper-case((/root/test/text())[1])',N'nvarchar(max)') Use_an_XQuery_method
```

And - once again - do not forget to place an `N` before your literals, when your strings contain *non-plain-latin* characters!!!

### UPDATE

As your example calls `.nodes()` I'd suggest to use `.nodes()` without bothering about the casing and do this in the `.value()` call:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = N'<root><test>1. Example //データベース/PO/Tbl_PO_H/DATA</test>
                           <test>2. Exmaple //データベース/PO/Tbl_PO_H/DATA</test>
                     </root>';
SELECT UPPER(Get_a_derived_table.testElement.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')) AS Use_a_TSQL_method
      ,Get_a_derived_table.testElement.value(N'upper-case(text()[1])',N'nvarchar(max)') Use_an_XQuery_method  
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/root/test') AS Get_a_derived_table(testElement);
```

### UPDATE 2: It seems to be the `XPath` which is different...

You can use the Asterisk `*` to get any node and `local-name()` in connection with `upper-case()` to set a *predicate* filtering the nodes needed:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = N'<root><データベース><PO><Tbl_PO_H><DATA>test with lower case</DATA></Tbl_PO_H></PO></データベース>
                           <データベース><PO><TBL_PO_H><DATA>test with UPPER case</DATA></TBL_PO_H></PO></データベース>
                     </root>';
SELECT A.B.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
FROM @xml.nodes(N'//データベース/PO/*[upper-case(local-name())=upper-case("Tbl_PO_H")]/DATA') AS A(B);
```

Comment: @xml is passed from C#. The problem is we have 2 kinds of XML files , one's XML node is Tbl_PO_H  and other is TBL_PO_H . So I must change the XML node to the same case (UPPER CASE) or LOWERCASE , but no way so far

Comment: @user3035133 , Sorry, not clear... Do you want to change the XML's content? This was a completely different issue...

Comment: Exactly is the XML node path. Because  //データベース/PO/Tbl_PO_H/DATA   and //データベース/PO/TBL_PO_H/DATA is differrent